# How do I route all network traffic through OpenVPN using network manager in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn, traffic

I am trying to connect to my university's VPN on a 15.10 machine. When I do it via the command line, all the traffic is routed through the VPN: That's what I want. When I load the same OpenVPN configuration (which is provided by our university) into Network Manager, the connection to the VPN still succeeds, but my traffic is not routed through the VPN. Other's have had the same (or the opposite problem on different Ubuntu versions - they didn't want everything to be routed, but could not change that behaviour). However, none of their solutions seems to work for me. I just switched from Mac to Linux and the Linux implementation of OpenVPN (Tunnelblick) had absolutely no problem with the same configuration file. Unfortuantely, Linux knowledge and support is very limited at our university (even though Linus Torvalds studied here...). Any hints are appreciated!

Below are the client configuration and the routes that I get when I connect with "openvpn /etc/openvpn/client.conf" and Network Manager, respectively:

/etc/openvpn/client.conf:

```
# Linux konfiguraatiotiedosto
# openvpn-2.x
verb 4
mlock
mtu-disc maybe
mtu-test
script-security 3
keepalive 60 360
redirect-gateway def1
dev tap
client
remote open.vpn.helsinki.fi
nobind
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
auth-user-pass
ca /etc/openvpn/HY-vpn-CA.pem
comp-lzo
```

Route after VPN establishment using command line:

```
mjeltsch@mjeltsch-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/etc/openvpn$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use     Iface
default         hy-vpn1-pa1veli 128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0  tap0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
128.0.0.0       hy-vpn1-pa1veli 128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tap0
128.214.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
openvpn1.fe.hel 192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlo1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```

Route after VPN establishment using Network Manager

```
mjeltsch@mjeltsch-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:/etc/openvpn$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 tap0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
128.214.5.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tap0
128.214.20.97   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlo1
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlo1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
```